# How to get a list of Xth elements from a list of tuples?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I need a sequential list of the all the first elements and another sequential list of all the 2nd elements in the list of tuples.

```
sset = [('foo',1),('bar',3),('zzz',9)]
x = ['foo','bar','zzz']
y = [1,3,9]
```

I am doing it this way:

```
x = [i for i,j in sset]
y = [j for i,j in sset]
```

**Is there a simpler way?**

I could use `dict.keys()` and `dict.values()` but is the order of the list kept? Also if my tuples have >2 elements the `dict` trick doesn't work.

```
x,y = dict(sset).keys(), dict(sset).values()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `zip()`, applying `sset` using the splat arbitrary arguments syntax `*args`:

```
x, y = zip(*sset)
```

Demo:

```
>>> sset = [('foo',1),('bar',3),('zzz',9)]
>>> x, y = zip(*sset)
>>> x
('foo', 'bar', 'zzz')
>>> y
(1, 3, 9)
```

This creates *tuples*, not lists; you can map the `zip()` output to lists as required:

```
x, y = map(list, zip(*sset))
```